# How to Calculate $\operatorname{Var}(X)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, variance, covariance

We choose a point $Y$ on pencil of length 1, S.T $Y\sim \operatorname{Uni}(0,1)$

We break the pencil at that point, choose one of the 2 parts in equal probability (1/2), S.T $X$ is the length of the part we chose. ie the length of the other part is $1-X$.

1. Calculate $\mathrm E(X)$.
2. Calculate $\operatorname{Var}(X)$.

For (1) I found that $X=Y$ or $X=1-Y$ in both cases where probability is 1/2 so the answer will be 1/2.

For (2) I know, $\operatorname{Var}(X)=\mathrm E(X^2)-\mathrm E(X)^2=\mathrm E(X^2)-1/4$ But How to Continue from here?

Comment: So $Y=X$ with probability 1/2 and $Y=l-X$ with probability 1/2. What can you say about the distributions $X$ and $l-X$? If it make it easier, try scaling the pencil to length 1, and se if you recognize anything.

Comment: @NikolajPedersen is E(X)=1/2 or am I wrong?

Comment: Any help with this?

Answer (score 1):

Since $X$ is uniform in the interval $[0,1]$, $E(X^2)=\int_0^1x^2dx=\frac{1}{3}$. Variance=$\frac{1}{12}$.

Comment: Take the random variable $\sigma \in \{1,-1\}$, both outcomes having equal probabilities, independently of $\mathsf{Y}$. Then take $\mathsf{X} = \frac{1-\sigma}{2} + \sigma \mathsf{Y}$. Then $\mathbf{E}[\mathsf{X}^2\, |\, \sigma]=1/3$ and $\mathbf{E}[\mathsf{X}\, |\, \sigma]=1/2$, both independently of $\sigma$ because the distribution of $\mathsf{X}$, conditional on $\sigma$, is uniform in either case. So it is best not to partition on the outcome of $\sigma$, just as [herb steinberg](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/501262/herb-steinberg) already indicated. I vote for his answer!

Comment: @ShannonStarr Then what's wrong with my method?

Comment: BTW X isn't given to be uniform, it's Y that is Uniform in interval [0,1]

Comment: You can prove $X$ is uniform.  It is not just given to you.  There are extra steps needed to justify the claim.

Comment: @Dan I do not know. I am not sure why you obtained 1/4 instead of 1/3 for the expectation of $\mathsf{X}^2$. The Uni(0,1) probability distribution has the property that if $\mathsf{Y}$ is distributed uniformly in $(0,1)$ then so is $1-\mathsf{Y}$. So no matter what value of $\sigma$ you get, the conditional distribution of $\mathsf{X}$, conditioning on $\sigma$ is Uni(0,1). That is what [Graham Kemp](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/135106/graham-kemp) is saying. I upvote Graham's comment.